# iframe the url output by a php script

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to take the currently logged in user id on my website and add it to the end of the URL to display in an iframe (iframe is for a third party website)
I have stumbled upon this code;

```
function makeClickableLink($text) {
    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);
    return $text;
}
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); // getting current user id from wordpress

$text = "http://example.com/something/something/?ba=310139&gd=927691&sid=$user_id"; // that's the link to a website i'm trying to iframe with my $user_id at the end
echo makeClickableLink($text);
```

http://example.com/something/something/?ba=310139&gd=927691&sid=1

So this code outputs the link that I put into the $text and replaces $user_id with the currently logged in users id which is so far exactly what I'm looking for.

Now.. Is there a way to iframe this link by modifying the above code ? (i have a plugin that allows me to use the iframe tags in wordpress before someone mentions that i can't use it there)  Or another  different way to do it? I need the above URL but in an iframe. I'm sure this is fairly easy to do however I cannot wrap my head around it (very new to all this but trying my best to learn :))

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Which plugin are you using? The above code is also outputting an <a> tag

Comment: **Warning 

`eregi_replace` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.**

Comment: I'm using advanced iframe pro which works well however I cannot find a way to pass the $user_id to the url. So far the only code I managed to find is the one above but that only results in a correct and clickable URL that I still need to iframe somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Pedro. What would you recommend I use instead of eregi_replace? edit: looks like I should be using preg_replace ? :)

Comment: [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Why would you need to use regular expressions here in the first place? If you want to put a variable value at the end of a given text, all you’d need in theory is basic _string concatenation_ … You have not told us how the plugin you are using comes into play here, so I’d suggest you go do that first.

Comment: According to http://www.tinywebgallery.com/blog/advanced-iframe/advanced-iframe-comparison-chart, in the pro version of that plugin, _“src attribute supports placeholders and shortcodes”_ – so that’s probably the reasonable way to go here.